# Using CASE statement in a Data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why this error?

Code:

```
declare @curr as varchar(10)
declare @var as numeric(10,5)

set @curr = 'RS'
set @var = 10.124523

SELECT 
    CAST(@var as numeric(17, CASE @curr WHEN 'RS' THEN 2 WHEN 'JPY' THEN 2 ELSE 4 END ) )
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: Why don't you use Round instead? If you are on SQL Server 2012 you can use format to display it with the appropriate number of digits.

Comment: The column should be either numeric(17,2) or numeric(17,4) it can't be both as these are different.

Comment: Any particular query will always produce a result set with a set, predefined "shape" - the number, name and data types of the columns are fixed. The only way "around" that is to construct a new query each time - dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done like that.

T-SQL doesn't allow you to use expressions when stating the data type. You will need to do dynamic sql, building it up through string concatenation, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but possibly could use if-else

```
declare @curr varchar(4)
declare @var numeric(17,5)

set @curr = 'rs'

if @curr = 'rs'
    select cast(@var as numeric(17,2)) var
else
    select cast(@var as numeric(17,2)) var
```